# "Module 'myapp' is not available" with Bootstraps collapse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm getting quite crazy here... I'm trying to use Bootstraps collapse functionality (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse). I'm new to AngularJS. I get the error "Module 'myapp' is not available!". I can't seem to find what's wrong with this code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('myapp').controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = false;
});
</script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
    <hr>
    <div collapse="isCollapsed">
        <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular the syntax for declaring a module is as below, where the modules dependencies are listed in the brackets.

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
```

When you want to retrieve a reference to the module, you do this - note how this time the brackets are not used.

```
angular.module('myapp')
```

You need to change your code so that it is like this:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = false;
});
```

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview